# Using an Intel Core i5 processor on a Core 2 Duo motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Is it possible to use an Intel Core i5 processor on a Core 2 Duo motherboard?

Is the Core 2 Duo processor chip shape the same as the Core i5's?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Core 2 Duo uses LGA 775.  Core i5 (depending on generation) uses LGA 1156, LGA 1366, or LGA 1155.  The sockets are not interchangable.

Comment: These presume you're talking about a desktop, naturally.

Comment: You beat me to it... Have an upvote.

Answer (score 12):

It is absolutely and unequivocally impossible.

The Core 2 Duo CPUs have no memory controller. They use an FSB to communicate with the Northbridge, which contains the memory controller. The Core i5 CPUs have a built-in memory controller and interface with the motherboard through a completely different interface (DMI).

So on a motherboard for a Core 2 Duo, the memory is wired to the Northbridge. On a motherboard for a Core i5, the memory is wired to the CPU. There is no way.

Comment: I still think my answer is technically more accurate since, yaknow, they don't fit anyway :) But this is some good technical info on the differences between the platforms (and that memory controller is the main reason there's so many more pins on the newer chips, IIRC) so have an upvote.

Comment: @Shinrai Socket adapters exist. The reason they don't exist for these two sockets is the reason I explained.